# Unhover Effect is flickering

Tags: css, vuejs3, laravel-blade, bootstrap-5

i have this html part of my nav element

```
<li id="forSwitch" class="nav-item mx-1" @mouseover="switchHover" @mouseout="switchUnHover">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa-solid fa-rotate" id="switch"></i></a>
    <div class="mx-2 hiddenIcons">
      <a href="#" class="mx-3" style="display:inline-block !important;">
        <img src="{{ URL('images/otherIcons/surplusIcon.png') }}" alt="surplus" id="surplus">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="mx-2" style="display:inline-block;">
        <img src="{{ URL('images/otherIcons/tradeIcon.png') }}" alt="trade" id="trade">
      </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

and this is the css:

```
#forSwitch {
    position:relative;
    width: 120px;
    border: solid 1px;

}

.hiddenIcons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    /* border: solid 1px;s */
}
```

and here's the js file:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    methods: {
        switchHover() {
            const swtch = document.getElementById('switch');
            swtch.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";

            const element = document.getElementsByClassName('hiddenIcons');
            for(let i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
                element[i].style.transform = "translateX(40%)";
                element[i].style.zIndex = "1";
                element[i].style.opacity = "1";
            }
        },
        switchUnHover() {
            const swtch = document.getElementById('switch');
            swtch.style.transform = "rotate(0)";

            const element = document.getElementsByClassName('hiddenIcons');
            
            // if()
            for(let i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
                element[i].style.transform = "translateX(0)";
                element[i].style.opacity = "0";
                setTimeout(function(){
                    element[i].style.zIndex = "-1";
                }, 300);
            }
        }
    }
}).mount("body");
```

as you guys can see, i'm trying to make an animation in my header. to make it short.
when the mouse hovers on the rotate-icon it will slide this div hiddenIcon with the two anchor elements to the left. Now when i unhover the rotate-icon but continue to hover to these two anchor inside the hiddenIcon. It will still display these hiddenIcon (which is what I wanted) but it has this annoying flickering effect.

i want this flickering gone but i want the unhover animation transition to be smooth instead of just disappearing.

i do think it's the setTimeout function because before. this is the code inside the switchUnHover() function

```
switchUnHover() {
            const swtch = document.getElementById('switch');
            swtch.style.transform = "rotate(0)";

            const element = document.getElementsByClassName('hiddenIcons');
            
            // if()
            for(let i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
                element[i].style.transform = "translateX(0)";
                element[i].style.opacity = "0";
                element[i].style.zIndex = "-1";
            }
        }
```

please help me. this is for my capstone project. and i'm the only one working with the code since my members don't know how to code.